# Visual representation of classes and/or objects

Tags: javascript, php, code-visualization

recently I started to work on some big project written in php/js.

It is really big and I have constant problem of backtracing what functions are called where.

Is there any tool, that would import all the code files and draw/write connections between classes, objects, functions and such?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BOUML can create UML diagrams out of your code

http://www.bouml.fr/

old 4.23 version is also free if that is needed

http://download.cnet.com/BOUML/3000-2094_4-10788888.html

Answer (score 2):

I am using Intellij IDEA with the PHP Storm Plugin for my PHP/JS-Projects. There I'm able to right click a function and choose "Find Usage    ALT+F7". Now I can see, where this function is getting called.

Intellij IDEA/PHP-Storm is also able to generate UML-Diagrams if needed.

I guess Netbeans, Eclipse+PHP-Plugin do have similar functions [maybe execpt of the uml-generator], if you need an IDE at no costs.